# Vue.js: Module not found

Tags: node.js, vue.js

For some days, My vue.js site was working fine in localhost. But suddenly I got this error(Module not found), while running npm start dev in Vue.js

"This dependency was not found:

*dev in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot.dev-server dev"

To install it, You can run:npm install --save dev

When i tried to install using the above command. it displayed the below error

Err Code EBADPLATFORM: Unsupported platform for inotify@1.4.2.

Comment: Probably just `npm start`

Comment: Thank you @ghybs. You saved my time.